# JS create rating score from 2 loops/arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a basic rating component that looks like this:

◼◼◼◻◻ (score: 3 out of 5)

I have the following code in JSX:

```
var score = 3; 
var range = 5;

{ [...Array(range)].map((e, i) => (
  <div className="rating-item" data-rating-count={ i + 1 }></div>
)) }
```

this returns the range but doesn't show the rating score:

```
◻ ◻ ◻ ◻ ◻
```

How can I combine the `score` and `range` values and add a class name `active` to the rating items?

I'm trying to get the following HTML:

```
<div class="rating-item active" data-rating-count="1"></div>
<div class="rating-item active" data-rating-count="2"></div>
<div class="rating-item active" data-rating-count="3"></div>
<div class="rating-item" data-rating-count="4"></div>
<div class="rating-item" data-rating-count="5"></div>
```

Which will output: ◼◼◼◻◻

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You need to modify your code like this

```
var score = 3; 
var range = 5;

{ [...Array(range)].map((e, i) => (
  <div className={"rating-item " + (i < score ? "active": "")} data-rating-count={ i + 1 }></div>
)) }
```